# Is it possible to direct VSCODE `python.Path` setting to a python interperter installed in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

The setup I work with has a docker container with Python and all relevant dependencies installed in it. The codebase itself (decoupled from the environment) is on the local machine, and gets mounted to the docker container when changes occur.

However, all Python highlighting and code completion, also in regard to the installed dependencies (mainly Django in this case) do not work in VSCODE since `python.Path` has no access to any interpreter.

I would prefer to avoid setting up a doubled venv on the local machine if possible. Is there a way to just connect VSCODE to the python environment available in the docker container?

Answer (score 1):

when using vscode, you can [develop inside a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

> Workspace files are mounted from the local file system or copied or cloned into the container. Extensions are installed and run inside the container, where they have full access to the tools, platform, and file system. This means that you can seamlessly switch your entire development environment just by connecting to a different container.

> This lets VS Code provide a local-quality development experience — including full IntelliSense (completions), code navigation, and debugging — regardless of where your tools (or code) are located.

Comment: But will i sustain git connection? I would have to install git on the container and make sure that .git folder is mounted? would that do it?

Comment: this wasn't your original question, so please create a new question and specify why my answer is not covering your issue so i could update it... and what is a git connection?